# Auto submit form when it has a value

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on a mobile app and I have an initial page that gets the users geolocation.  I want to automatically submit this form after we successfully have the users geolocation.  I am using jquery and jquery mobile if that helps any.  Thanks!

```
</head> 
<body>
 <div id="location">
 <form action="/location" method="POST" id="location" name="location">
        <input type="text" id="lat" name="lat" />
        <input type="text" id="long" name="long" />
        <input type="submit" value="Set my location" data-theme="b" /></form>

      </div>
      <script>
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          function(pos) {
            $("#lat").val(pos.coords.latitude);
            $("#long").val(pos.coords.longitude);
            load();
          }
        );
      </script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better solution is to set events *onchange* for both inputs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var state1 = false;
    var state2 = false;
    var sbm = function(form) {
        form.submit();
    };
    $('input#lat')
        .change(function() {
            state1 = true;
            if (state1 && state2) 
                sbm($(this).parent());
        });
    $('input#long')
        .change(function() {
            state2 = true;
            if (state1 && state2) 
                sbm($(this).parent());
        });
});
```

Comment: Kacper this is a great suggestion but it's not working when I try it..do I have to specify the form?  It looks like it just goes for the parent form.  Should this be in the <head></head> area?

Comment: Kacper actually it is working but it only works when I manually change the input.  Right now my code is changing the input value of the forms when the page loads the gelocation info.  It doesn't seem to submit when that script changes the input.

Comment: So tell me what load() function does in your code. Maybe I can help you.

Comment: Kacper not really sure the code you see above is what I'm using.  Got it from an example of obtaining lat& long.

Comment: You can put code from functions which are called 'onchange' into anonymous function called by navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition. To make sure that form won't br submitted before setting data, you can use jQuery.queue() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for setTimeOutfunction()

Here is a link you may like:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Just call a function with settimeout function that will check the value and if you have the value, then submit the form.

Hope this helps..